# Repeat a token specific number of times in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, date-formatting

I want to design a rule that expresses date format types
like :

- 'ddmmyyyy'
- 'dd/mm/yyyy'
- 'mm/dd/yyyy'
- 'dd-mm-yyyy'
- 'yyyymmdd'

I tried this in Lexer, but it didn't work (token recognition error)

```
fragment DATE_SEPARATOR: ('/'|',');

FORMATE
: '\'' (MONTH{1,2} (DATE_SEPARATOR)? DAY{1,2}  (DATE_SEPARATOR)? YEAR{1,4}
| DAY{1,2}  (DATE_SEPARATOR)? MONTH{1,3}  (DATE_SEPARATOR)? YEAR{1,4}
| YEAR{1,4}  (DATE_SEPARATOR)? MONTH{1,3}  (DATE_SEPARATOR)? DAY{1,2})
;
fragment DAY : ('d'|'D'|'day'|'DAY') ;
fragment MONTH : ('m'|'M'|'Mon'|'Month'|'mon'|'month') ;
fragment YEAR : ('y'|'Y'|'Year'|'year'|'Yr'|'yr') ;
```

I only called FORMATE in parser with SINGLE_QUOTE after it which refer to ' in Lexer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{1,4}` is not supported by ANTLR. If you want to match something between 1 and 4 times, you need to do:

```
NUMBER : D (D (D D?)?)?;

fragment D : [0-9];
```

But when you do `YEAR{1,4}` and the `YEAR` fragment matches `('y'|'Y'|'Year'|'year'|'Yr'|'yr')`, then, if `{1,4}` was valid, you'd  successfully match `"YearYrYyr"` (4 times the `YEAR` fragment). However, that seems a bit odd.

Comment: What's the difference between `D (D (D D?)?)?` and `D D? D? D?` The latter seems easier for me to read unless there's a definite advantage of using the nested paren approach.

Comment: @carl: `D D? D? D?` is ambiguous. (Which D is missing if one is missing?) `D (D (D D?)?)?` is not.